# What is the connection betweeen birthday paradox and sublinear sortedness testing

Tags: probability

I was reading [this article](https://sublinear-course.wikispaces.com/file/view/lecture2.pdf). On the first page there is statement in part 2, that when we randomly pick 2 indeccs each iteration, then we'll have to select $s=\Omega(\sqrt(n))$ different iterations. And that can be calculated with birthday paradox. I don't see the relation between this two parts.

I see it this way:
in total we can pick $n \choose 2$ index pairs each iteration. Indeces are ordered.
We have $\frac {n}{2}$ ordered pairs which can catch unsortedness.
So the probability to catch it:
$p=\frac{\frac {n}{2}}{{{n} \choose {2}}}$.

Probability of error in 1 iteration is 
$q=1-p=p=1-\frac{\frac {n}{2}}{{{n} \choose {2}}}$

Probability of error in s runs is 
$q^s$.

Then $s=\Omega(n)$.
But in the article stated that $s=\Omega(\sqrt(n))$
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me include what the question is asking about, in case the site goes down:

[image: Screenshot image from the question's link]

Firstly, I'd say it doesn't matter: they're only saying that (with high probability) we'll need to select $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$ pairs, so if you think you've found a better lower bound $\Omega(n)$, then it doesn't contradict their claim: any function that is $\Omega(n)$ is also $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$, so you've just proved a stronger result than theirs: either way we know that this test won't work.

Secondly, nothing is wrong in your analysis; your analysis is correct for your (natural) understanding of the algorithm: if on each iteration we choose a pair $(x_i, x_j)$ independently of all previous choices, then indeed the probability of success in any given iteration is $p = \frac{n}{2} / \binom{n}{2}$, so we need an expected number of $1/p = \Theta(n)$ iterations till we are successful.

What their analysis does is in fact rule out all similar/smarter algorithms one can get by tweaking this algorithm: suppose we say we're going to *remember* our choices from earlier iterations and not choose the same numbers again, also we're somehow going to compare *all* the numbers we've selected so far to see if some pair is out of order. Then, still, we have $n/2$ buckets from which we're drawing balls, two at a time, so by the birthday paradox we need $\Omega(\sqrt{n/2})$ drawings until we happen to randomly draw twice from the same bucket. This is the same as $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: thanks it helped. How the upper bound can be shown?

Comment: @Nathan: Do you mean, what is the algorithm that has upper bound of $O(\sqrt{n})$ on not just the number of items selected, but also its running time?

Comment: I don't get how to shove upper bound $k \le \frac {n}{\eps}$.

Comment: I don't think that's related to this question, is it? Also I don't see any $k$ in the notes, nor do I see $\frac{n}{\epsilon}$ anywhere.

Comment: Everything is fine. Thanks!